# Entity framework exception when saving more than 1 object in a 1 to many relationship, when we have inheritance

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ado.net

I have created a very simple test model, and I have come across a problem.

If I have a relationship of 1 to many, which then has a relationship of 1 - 0...1. If I create more than 1 object to add to the model on the 1 to many side, I get the following exception:

```
Unable to determine the principal end of the 
'TestModel.FK__Transacti__Trans__023D5A04' relationship. 
Multiple added entities may have the same primary key.
```

This is the model I am dealing with:

[image]

The entity framework code I am using to do the save is as follows:

```
using (TestEntities context = new TestEntities())
        {
            // create test sales 
            SalesOrderHeader salesHeader = new SalesOrderHeader();
            salesHeader.Transactions = new List<Transaction>();
            salesHeader.SalesDate = DateTime.Now;

            // create test payment
            TransactionPayment payment = new TransactionPayment();
            payment.SalesOrderHeader = salesHeader;
            payment.TransactionDate = DateTime.Now;

            // attach the payment to the sale
            salesHeader.Transactions.Add(payment);

            // create another test payment
            payment = new TransactionPayment();
            payment.SalesOrderHeader = salesHeader;
            payment.TransactionDate = DateTime.Now;
            
            // attach the 2nd payment to the sale
            salesHeader.Transactions.Add(payment);

            // add the sale to the context and save the changes
            context.SalesOrderHeaders.AddObject(salesHeader);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
```

The model basically reads, that we have 1 sales header. For each sales header, we have multiple transaction objects. And each transaction object can be of type transaction payment. Ignore the simpleness of this model, it is a majorly cut down version of what I am trying to do, but it hits the exact same exception as the real model.

So, transaction payment inherits from transaction, and I have removed the primary key on transaction payment as it conflicted with the key on transaction....namely the "TransactionID" column.

If I save one transaction at a time it will work. If I manually set the transaction ID's to be different numbers on both payment objects it works. However, if I don't set the keys I get that exception. The ID field is an auto incrementing number in the DB, so I shouldn't really be setting the key to some imaginary number that will then get overwritten after the save surely?

Is there something I am doing wrong?

Comment: You should delete the `0 - 0..1` relation in the diagram. It could be the error and it should be removed anyway.

Comment: It's better to post code as text, not an image. That way we can copy/paste, and it's google-friendly.

Comment: Ah sorry Tim, I normally do, but wasn't really thinking about copy/paste :S

Comment: Henk, you were spot on!! I assumed that relationship needed to be kept! Can you post up an answer and I'll mark it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should delete the `0 - 0..1` relation in the diagram. It is replaced by the inheritance that you have added. Notice there are no corresponding Nav properties.

And as it turns out this was the actual error.